# min- and max value of an array in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to get the minimum and maximum value of an array. The problem is that I'm not sure what exactly happens in the `for loop`. We create a `for loop` with an `int`. Then comes the if statement and also my question: **What should `numbers[i]` mean?** I thought that `numbers` already has specified size (9, by initializing **{ 1,2,3,...,9}**). How can we change that to `[i]` and what does that i stand for?

```
public class Array {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int numbers[] = { 92, -108, 2, 120, 67, 4, -81, 9, 88, 1 };
    int min, max;
    min = max = numbers[0];

    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
        if (numbers[i] < min)
            min = numbers[i];
        if(numbers[i] > max){
            max = numbers[i];
        }
    }
    System.out.println("min is: " + min + "; max is: " + max);
}
}
```

Looking forward to your replies

Comment: numbers[i] references an individual number in the array.  so for example numbers[0] is 92, numbers[1] is -108 etc.

Answer (score 2):

`numbers[i]` is how you access the *ith* element in the array.

Answer (score 1):

As Andrew Rueckert [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37820356/1850301), in Java, as well as in most other major languages, `array[i]` notation provides access to ith element of array `array`. You may use square brackets `[]` to specify the size of an array in its definition, for example:

```
int[] array = new int[10];
```

But later on, you use brackets to specify to which element of the array you want to have access to. In your example, there is `for` loop iterating from 1 to 10. In each iteration it reads current (ith) element from the array `numbers`.

Comment: Okay, so i should take it just how it is - no magic or big logic behind it - to get to to i-th element, you use array[i]. If i get it right, it is [i] because we're in a for loop. If I want, i can type array[1] = x, array[2] = y, etc and it's exactly the same thing

Comment: @Rio, `array[0]` gives you access to the first element of an array, `array[1]` to the second and so on. There is `numbers[i]` inside your `for` loop because in this loop you initialize `int i`, which is being incremented in each step of the loop. So by `numbers[i]` nested in your `for` loop you are subsequently getting access to every element of the array `numbers`.

Answer (score 0):

Lets take the barebones of what you are trying to understand

```
int numbers[] = { 92, -108, 2, 120, 67, 4, -81, 9, 88, 1 };
int min, max;
min = max = numbers[0];

for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
    if (numbers[i] < min)
        min = numbers[i];
    if(numbers[i] > max){
        max = numbers[i];
    }
}
```

First, you are initializing an array of numbers to whatever you have within the `{}`. So you have an array that is of length 10. Then we declare two `int`'s min and max. The values are as such:

```
numbers[0] = 92;
numbers[1] = -108;
numbers[2] = 2;
numbers[3] = 120;
numbers[4] = 67;
numbers[5] = 4;
numbers[6] = -81;
numbers[7] = 9;
numbers[8] = 88;
numbers[9] = 1;
```

The next statement is declaring `min` and `max` as the very first element of the array (0 is the first, all the way up to size-1 for arrays, which in this case is 9).

```
min = numbers[0] (92).
max = numbers[0] (92).
```

Next part is the for loop, which is where all the calculations come into play. The for loop is saying start an `int` named `i` off at 1. Everytime you go through this loop, compare the boolean value in the middle, which in this case is `i < 10` which means as long as `i` is less than 10, stay in the loop. After each iteration, do the third operation which in this case is `i++`, which means increment `i` variable by 1.

Great, we are going through the for loop. Lets start off with the first iteration, which means `i` is 1. We are taking the SECOND element of the `numbers` array (0 is the first element, remember?) and comparing that with the current value of `min` first (which is the first element of the array, 92).

Well if you look at the values, -108, which is the second element in the array, is less than min. Therefore, `min` is set to the first element in the array now. Next, we compare -108 and see if it is greater than `max`, which again is 92. -108 is NOT greater than 92, so it skips that if statement.

```
i = 1
min = numbers[1] (-108).
max = numbers[0] (92).
```

Lets go through the second iteration of the for loop. Since we got to the end, we do the `i++` statement. Now we are at `i` = 2. Lets check to make sure we dont exit. Is the value of `i` less than 10? Yes so lets continue from the top!

Is numbers[2] (which is 2) less than the current value of `min` (-108)? No, skip that if statement. is numbers[2] greater than the current value of max (92)? No, lets take another look at the values:

```
i = 2
min = numbers[1] (-108)
max = numbers[0] (92)
```

Next, since we are at the bottom, do `i++`. `i` now equals 3.

This continues all the way through till `i` = 9, because when `i` = 10, it exits out of the for loop due to that middle statement in the for loop, the exit clause.

Comment: Awesome explanation! I think i get it, the only thing that bothers me is "We are taking the SECOND element of the numbers array (0 is the first element, remember?) and comparing that with the current value of min first" - i don't quite understand that numbers[i] - how can we set our array to the integer of the for loop?

Comment: @Rio I updated a little. But when you say `numbers[i]`, you are saying get me the value of `i` which is declared in the for loop, and then get me that element from within the array. So if `i` equals 1, and you say `numbers[i]`, we want to get the second element of the array, because in arrays, 0 is first and 1 is second all the way down. As others have said, you want the ith element in the array.

Answer (score 0):

If u want get min and max value from array, you can use sort() method from java.util Arrays class.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class TestClass {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] numbers = { 92, -108, 2, 120, 67, 4, -81, 9, 88, 1 };
    // print your array (no sorted)
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numbers));

    Arrays.sort(numbers);
    //print your array (sorted)
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numbers));

    for(int i = 0; i<numbers.length;i++){
        System.out.println("My array: ["+i+"] " +numbers[i]);
        // min = numbers[0] = -108
        // My array: [0] -108
        // My array: [1] -81
        // My array: [2] 1
        // My array: [3] 2
        // My array: [4] 4
        // My array: [5] 9
        // My array: [6] 67
        // My array: [7] 88
        // My array: [8] 92
        // My array: [9] 120
        // max = numbers[9] = 120
    }
}
}
```